# How to run a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I'm a programming newbie, and I can't figure out how to store a function in JQuery and run in it multiple places.

I have:

```
$(function () {
  $("div.class").click(function(){
    //Doo something

  });

  $("div.secondclass").click(function(){
    //Doo something
  });

});
```

Now the 2 "//Doo somethings" are the same, and I don't want to write the same code again.

If I put:

```
$(function () {

  function doosomething ()
  {
    //Doo something
  }

  $("div.class").click(doosomething);

  $("div.secondclass").click(doosomething);

});
```

That would run the function on page load, rather than only when it clicks.

How do I do this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The following should work nicely.

```
$(function() {

  // Way 1
  function doosomething()
  {
    //Doo something
  }

  // Way 2, equivalent to Way 1
  var doosomething = function() {
    // Doo something
  }

  $("div.class").click(doosomething);

  $("div.secondclass").click(doosomething);

});
```

Basically, you are declaring your function in the same scope as your are using it (JavaScript uses [Closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) to determine scope).

Now, since functions in JavaScript behave like any other object, you can simply assign `doosomething` as the function to call on click by using `.click(doosomething);`

Your function will not execute until you call it using `doosomething()` (`doosomething` without the `()` refers to the function but doesn't call it) or another function calls in (in this case, the `click` handler).

Comment: Thank you for way 2, I'll have to try that. But the function is indeed ran on page load because in jquery $(function() is shorthand for document load. So way 1 at least, will not work.

Comment: I am very new to jQuery, so can you explain the first line `$(function() {`? What is the purpose of this line, please? tyvm

Comment: $ is a shorthand for 'jQuery'. So everytime you see '$' somewhere, you have to think this is the jQuery function, the $(function(){}); will make it so that no particular event is specified: the code will be executed when the document is ready. $(function(){}); === jQuery(document).ready(function(){}); or $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 29):

I would do it this way:

```
(function($) {
jQuery.fn.doSomething = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // Your function goes here
      });
   });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then on document ready you can do stuff like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#div1').doSomething();
   $('#div2').doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Does creating a function outside the "document ready" actually provide any benefits?

Comment: @Nuktu yes, for plugin development.

Comment: If you're using $ in the function parameter, then why bother calling it jQuery instead of using $ again?

Comment: It passes jQuery so that this version works even if you have other libraries that assign to $. The formal parameter and its uses inside the function have local scope and thus won't conflict the way the passed object name could.

Comment: why do you have the $ in the parens instead of before

Answer (score 18):

```
function doosomething ()
{
  //Doo something
}


$(function () {


  $("div.class").click(doosomething);

  $("div.secondclass").click(doosomething);

});
```

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively (I'd say preferably), you can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("div.class, div.secondclass").click(function(){
    //Doo something
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice when f.e div.secondclass doesn't exist yet... NOT!

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this - Since you want one function to be used everywhere, you can do so by directly calling JqueryObject.function(). For example if you want to create your own function to manipulate any CSS on an element:

```
jQuery.fn.doSomething = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   return this;
}
```

And the way to call it:

```
$("#someRandomDiv").doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the most obfuscated solution possible? I don't believe the idea of jQuery was to create code like this.There's also the presumption that we don't want to bubble events, which is probably wrong.

Simple moving `doosomething()` outside of `$(function(){}` will cause it to have global scope and keep the code simple/readable.

Comment: But if it is used only in JQuery functions, it is much better not to pollute the global scope and keep it where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way that I do it in Modern JavaScript:

```
$(
  $("div.class").click(() => {doosomething});
  $("div.secondclass").click(() => {doosomething});
);
```