# How to correctly run JS after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload, document-ready

Working on cleaning up my errors and depreciated web-pages, 
I've run into this Warning Message:

> jquery-3.4.1.js:9725 
>   [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. 
>   For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I want to properly handle the JavaScript right:

1. Keep the scripts and links in a self-contained area, i.e.
2. Run after the page loads

But I don't know how to:

1. Convert from inline JS references to JS-file
2. What the internal JS format should look like

I've been using:

```
<head>

    <script>$(document).ready(function () { $('<script/>', { type: 'text/javascript', src: 'assets/js/set-background.js' }).appendTo('head'); }); </script>

</head>
```

With the JS-file:

```
...
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.className += " change-" + idx;
...
```

The warning doesn't happen if the script is:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="assets/js/set-background.js"></script>
    ...
</body>
```

And tried,

```
<head>

    <script>$(function(){'assets/js/set-background.js'}) </script>

</head>
```

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/set-background.js"></script>

</head>
```

```
<body class="container" onload="assets/js/set-background.js">
```

I've seen other developers discussions:

1. [javascript - How to run a function when the page is loaded? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/how-to-run-a-function-when-the-page-is-loaded)
2. [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)
3. [javascript - $(document).ready equivalent without jQuery - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)
4. [How to run a function in jquery - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191833/how-to-run-a-function-in-jquery)

And I've also been reading:

1. [onload Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)
2. [.load() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: This would be the correct one: <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/set-background.js"></script>

Comment: This one didn't work, the issue is that I need to run the script after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning isn't related to page load. The problem is that somewhere you used an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) with 'async' parameter `false`.

This isn't good, because of the JS event loop behavior (single thread), so if the download of requested data takes longer time, the page completely freezes: no clicks, scrolling, other JS functions, nothing!

To solve the issue, you have to use asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, or the [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Okay, so how do I find the XMLHttpRequest? 

The warning didn't happen until I tried to reformat the code, and I'm unfamiliar with finding where implicit async parameters might be.

Comment: @zach Search for something like: `xhr=new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open(/*something*/,/*something*/,false)`. And you can't create a linebreak in a comment ;)

Comment: @zach Or if you're using jQuery it could be `$.ajax`